# Tool for localizers to generate rough layout preview images of an Android app in other language?

Tags: localization, android-layout

For my open-source Android app, many users contribute **localizations** to tens of languages.
They are **not developers**, and some don't even have an Android device, so they can not compile to **view immediately how it looks**.

Question: Is there a webapp or tool that takes the layout and localization XML files, mixes them, and **generates images** of the various screens?

It would not be perfect (many strings appear only in generated dialogs), but better than nothing.
Right now translators can not see how it looks until I release a beta version.
That would motivate translators a lot, and lead to translations of better quality (especially for text lengths).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Eclipse does this with the ADT plugin.

Just open a layout XML file, select the "Graphical layout" tab, and change the language using the dropdown menu.